# Battery LED blinking orange?

Tags: lubuntu, laptop, 18.04

As of recently, my laptop (Satellite C640D), whenever it has been unplugged, its battery LED starts blinking orange... I have no explanation on why it is doing this, but it bugs me and i want it to go away :/

Any solutions y'all can think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of fixes that seem to resolve this issue and you can find them by searching the internet. This one seems to mention a number of them: http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2348754/toshiba-satellite-laptop-turn-blinking-orange-light.html

This is not an Ubuntu issue and it appears to be resolved by hardware solutions.